# Why does it take a long time to upload photos to Flickr using iPhoto '11?

Tags: photos.app, flickr

I take a lot of photos and use iPhoto to manage everything.  I also have a Premium Flickr account where everything gets sent to in order to have an online presence.

Whenever I use the 'Share' option in iPhoto to send them to Flickr, no matter how many photos I try and upload it takes a very long time.  After a while it doesn't seem to be actually uploading anymore, but something is causing the process to hang, but I can't tell what.  It has currently been about 90 mins and with the absence of any progress bar or indicator I can't be sure when this will end, or why it's taking so long.

UPDATE: After checking my Flickr sets online, two of the sets and several photos (about 50) are not yet uploaded

Does anything have any advice to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try an export plugin and see if it's any faster? Otherwise, it might be a limitation of your connection.

- [FlickrExport](http://connectedflow.com/flickrexport/iphoto/)
- [FFXporter](http://dustin.li/code/ffxporter/)